# ShareKit -Evernote integration to iPhone App

Tags: iphone, sharekit

I prefered to use the sharekit for the social integration to my iphone app. While configuring the evernote integration when i tested with the default credentails its worked but when I used  my own credentails it doesn't work. The alert says the "your username and password did not match" for same credentails used before.

The Default code(working) was

```
- (NSString*)evernoteUserStoreURL {
    return @"https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/user";
}

- (NSString*)evernoteNetStoreURLBase {
    return @"http://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/note/";
}

- (NSString*)evernoteConsumerKey {
    return @"<shareKit's key>";
}

- (NSString*)evernoteSecret {
    return @"<shareKit's secret>";
}
```

i just changed the key and secret with mine. Nothing else at all. and its not working
my code is

```
- (NSString*)evernoteUserStoreURL {
    return @"https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/user";
}

- (NSString*)evernoteNetStoreURLBase {
    return @"http://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/note/";
}

- (NSString*)evernoteConsumerKey {
    return @"<mykey>";    // replaced by my key
}

- (NSString*)evernoteSecret {
    return @"<mysecret>";  // replaced by my secret
}
```

Its all about sandbox.evernote.com. On evernote.com, none of the above is working. Please suggest me what else to configure?

Comment: Can you tell me if apple have not approved or not accept share kit then why some person have try with Share kit?

Comment: What? Many apps are on the appstore with share kit incorporated, which were approved, including mine. Can you tell me more? I do not think the reason for reject is ShareKit, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

edit 2: [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/shareKit/ShareKit/) has just been updated to use newest Evernote iOS sdk. This problem should be gone now.

<del>edit: it seems that ShareKit's Evernote implementation is obsolete - they have changed authentication API to support OAuth. Until someone updates ShareKit's Evernote sharer, new apps are out of luck. Though the trick with deleting cookies might help, as this error showed up 2 months ago (on ShareKit's github issue tracker), and mandatory OAuth is fresh new.</del>

<del>You must use Evernote sandbox environment only during implementation phase. When you are ready for production, you can [apply](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/) Evernote for approval of your API key for production environment.
Make sure, that you connect to sandbox environment with your **sandbox test account**, not the real one. You can create sandbox account [here](https://sandbox.evernote.com/Registration.action).</del>

<del>Make sure, that you do not use any special characters for test account name or password.</del>

Maybe you could try to delete cookies during app startup after changing app credentials in configurator. You can do it within ShareKit using ShareKit's NSHTTPCookieStorage category:

```
[NSHTTPCookieStorage deleteCookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SHKCONFIG(evernoteUserStoreURL)]];
```

I am not sure, if the url is the right one to delete cookies - this might need some experimentation.